# SwiperJs in Angular - move 3 slides on click

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I am jusing SwiperJs library with Angular.

i want to implement feature, where on click I go next (or previous) for 3 slides not just 1 slide.

Normal arrows work fine, code:

```
  scrollLeft() {
    this.swiper!.swiperRef.slidePrev(500);
    this.scrollArrows();
  }

  scrollRight() {
    this.swiper!.swiperRef.slideNext(500);
    this.scrollArrows();
  }
```

But It goes next or prev just for 1 slide. (I tried writing three same lines but it does not work).

Config object:

```
  swiperConfig: any = {
    slidesPerView: 'auto',
    loop: true,
    spaceBetween: 20,
    autoplay: {
      delay: 1000,
      disableOnInteraction: false,
    },
  };
```

Thanks to everyone for help.

Answer (score 0):

Slides Per View, Slides Per View Auto, or Slides Per Group.
In the JS script code:

```
slidesPerView: 3,
spaceBetween: 20,
```